# How can I write to a directory owned by ROOT when not running as ROOT for a Tomcat Docker Image that I don't want to edit?

Tags: docker, tomcat, kubernetes, containers, root

I have a docker image that I am trying to run using K8s. I can get it to run on my home environment but not at my workplace as we cannot run as root on the k8 cluster.

The docker image is a Tomcat server with a WAR file that lives here:

**/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war**

During start-up Tomcat tries to explode the WAR into a directory here:

**/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT**

But it can't do this because /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ is owned by ROOT.

So I thought the best way to solve was to mount a volume with an emptyDir{} like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers: 
    ...
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: //usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
      name: tomcat
  volumes:
  - name: tomcat
    emptyDir: {}
```

But this doesn't work because it just makes an empty ROOT folder under webapps which  Tomcat can't explode the WAR to because it expects to create ROOT it self.

I also tried this:

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: //usr/local/tomcat/webapps
      name: tomcat
```

But now /webapps is just an empty folder because I assume I'm overwriting what the container is setting up for me when it starts up.

I'm obviously missing something fundemental here...I don't want to edit the image as I believe there must be another way around this I simply want /tomcat/webapps to be writable by the runAsUser which isn't root.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What image are you running? Is it one you built yourself, or one available from docker hub? In either case, is it one that we could take a look at? My immediate reaction is that the image is buggy, or at least poorly designed such that it assumes it is running as `root`.

Comment: @larks Thanks for your concern the image can be found here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/plantuml/plantuml-server

plantuml/plantuml-server:tomcat

The Jetty image also has a similar problem in that it tries to make a new file under /var/lib

Answer (score 3):

If you don't already have one, just create a Dockerfile for your image and add following lines into it:

```
...

ENV USER=<YOUR-CONTAINER-USER>
ENV UID=10014
ENV GID=10014
RUN addgroup "$USER" --gid "$GID" \
    && adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "$(pwd)" \
    --ingroup "$USER" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "$UID" \
    "$USER"
RUN chown -R "$USER":"$USER" /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT

USER "$USER"

...
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to fix that is via an `initContainer:`, although [`fsGroup:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod) is the more declarative way of fixing that, so long as your cluster's security policy allows setting that field

```yaml
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: chown
    image: docker.io/library/busybox:latest
    command:
    - chown
    - -R
    - whatever-the-uid-is-for-your-tomcat-image
    - /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
      name: tomcat
  containers:
  # ... as before
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting that the busybox container does not contain the same users as the tomcat container? Also, how will you copy the application WAR into this volume?

Comment: I said uid, not user, since `chown bob` is just syntatic sugar for `chown $(awk -F: '/^bob/{print $2}' /etc/passwd)` and the objective was never to copy the WAR into that volume, it was to make the `ROOT` directory not owned by root so the main container can write into it. It's entirely possible the `webapps` directory needs to be chown-ed also, but that's not what the original question asked about

Comment: It does not matter whether you use uid or users, the images have different users pre-installed. So, you will have to make sure that the uid you use is known by both images, e.g. nobody.  Regarding the webapps directory, it is supposed to contain ROOT.war.

Comment: That is demonstrably false and you should carefully consider whether leaving such a comment on a technical website is helpful: `docker run --rm -it busybox sh -exc 'touch fred.txt; chown 12345 fred.txt; ls -l fred.txt; grep 12345 /etc/passwd'` cheerfully shows `-rw-r--r--    1 12345    root`

Comment: Two points: of course you can set the user in the busybox container to some arbitrary id, but that is no good, if that user is not known to the tomcat container, since it won't be able to run those files. Secondly, I feel you are getting personal and defensive to I will not be continuing this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I propose solving this **on a Docker level**, since you most likely will have to create a child image for your application anyway. This approach has the merit that you can test before deploying to K8s. Also, you produce a higher quality image and not one that requires "tweaking" for save deployment.

Doing this with Docker would look like this:

```
FROM tomcat
RUN addgroup --system -gid 1000 app && adduser --system -uid 1000 -gid 1000 app
RUN chown -R app /usr/local/tomcat/
USER app
COPY --chown=1000:root your-war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

Any K8s based solution, like overwriting the webapp folder with a volume and assigning non-root permissions to that volume, suffers from the problem that it will be hard to copy your WAR into the webapp folder. While complicated contraptions with init-containers would be theoretically possible, they are brittle and overly complicated (for starters you would have to ensure same users and groups in init container and main container. Also, your WAR would need to be in the init container).

Comment: thanks for that...if the WAR is already part of the image I don't need to copy it over right? I just need to do the chown -R bit

Comment: That's right. You copy it over when building the image.

Comment: This doesn't work I still get the same error - here is my Dockerfile:

RUN addgroup --system -gid 1000 app && adduser --system -uid 1000 -gid 1000 app
RUN chown -R app /usr/local/tomcat/
USER app

Then in my k8 deployment I've got runAsUser set to 1000.

Comment: If you copied my Dockerfile as is, there was an error: it said "/usr/local/tomcat/webapp" rather than "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps". Other than that, it works - I just tested it to make sure.